# Buffered output in chunks and shortcode - how do I achieve that?

Tags: plugins, shortcode

**I wonder how to achieve outputbuffering in chunks when using a shortcode?**

**Without outbuffering:**
(This works and gets at correct location (under the actual header in template because of return $html;)

```
add_shortcode( 'showtable', array ( $this, 'source_to_table') );
function source_to_table( $attrs ) 
{
    code...
    $html = '';
    for($row_values as $r) {
        $html .= $r . '<br>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

**With outbuffering:**
(This works but is located directly at top (before the actual header in template because no return exists. but if I have a return then whole point of using output buffering chunks are gone!?)

```
add_shortcode( 'showtable', array ( $this, 'buffered_source_to_table') );
function buffered_source_to_table( $attrs ) 
{
    code...
    $chunk = 0;
    for($row_values as $r) {
        ob_start();
        echo $r.'<br>';
        $chunk++;
        if ($chunk % 100 == 0) ob_flush();
    }
    ob_flush();
    
}
```

Comment: this sounds like you have a solution you want to use for your problem just because, not because it fits your problem. Sounds like you do not understand well what chunking is. personally never were in situation where chunking made a difference, especially as they break zipping your html and you will pay a cost for tranmitting larger file which might negate whatever you trying to do.

Comment: and then, I might not understand what you mean when you talk about chunking

Comment: With an example an array of 20.000 rows ... I mean to create an output buffer in a chunk (in above case 100 rows at time and then print the outbuffer out to the browser) so the user experience will be better. If not doing that my chrome freezes because it takes to long time. I took like 2-3 seconds with my second example in total, but it prints out before the actual "content" area in wordpress. I maybe do not understand well what chunking is but I do understand what speed is :-)

Comment: Trust me. I've been thinking of different solutions, but the main issue is the slow display of large amounts of data from a shortcode that is the issue. With some comments from @Jacob Peattie I think I will move on using pagination/ajax (because I already have support for that in my plugin. I just need a way of saving the file in a good way).

Comment: browser will wait unill all chunks arrive before displaying anything, if you send it in html. you first want to do it in ajax as that will deliver "chunks" in a more "make sense" way, but..... if there is a lot of data the browser most likely will not be able to display all of it due to PC's memory limitation. You need to think on better way to displaying the data maybe with some kind of filtering, or "page" it to limit the mount of data being displayed.

Comment: oh scrap it how browsers will display it, I am not sure if it is defined anywhere so maybe they will if your html is valid enough after each chunk.

Comment: "browser will wait unill all chunks arrive before displaying anything, if you send it in html. " If that is true, what's point of using output buffering at all?

Comment: Why shouldn't the html be valid?

Comment: as I said above, don't believe chunking is useful for a web page, it might be useful to send a stream of data. The HTML is invalid because until the '</html>' tag it is not a valid HTML, but browsers are good at working with partial HTML to speed up rendering so you might get lucky.

Comment: I solved this without using output buffering. I used pagination/ajax instead as I stated earlier. What I did is that I saved all csv-file into a div but that div was set to display:none, and when the dom has loaded I set it to display block. This speeds up the process very much. This in conjunction with pagination where I merged together the editable (visible inputs) values with the div with csv-file values. I won't even use output buffer in any way in wordpress because there are too many risks (plugin conflicts, debugging info dont show etc) with rather little performance boost.

Answer (score 1):

Chunks are irrelevant. Just use output buffering to capture the entire output and then return the result at the end:

```
function buffered_source_to_table( $attrs ) 
{
    ob_start();

    for($row_values as $r) {
        echo $r.'<br>';
    }
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

After `ob_start();` any output (from `echo`, for example) is captured by the output buffer. You then just need to return the contents of the buffer for your shortcode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't agree with you though. Chunks are irrelevant when having a table of for example 300 rows, but having a table of 20.000 rows makes a huge difference when using output buffering in chunks. It displays to the user and does not timeout/freeze the browser. (The actual plugin is generating a html table from a csv file)

Comment: I'm talking about shortcodes. A shortcode callback needs to return a string that replaces the shortcode in content. What you're describing isn't really going to work in a shortcode because the shortcode substitution is done whole before any content is output.

Comment: So you're basically saying output buffering in chunks isn't possible within a shortcode?

Comment: I'm not aware of a method, but it's not necessarily my area of expertise.

Comment: Ok thank you! I might elloborate more on my problem and the thing is that I want to show all rows because a csv-file must be saved in "one piece" and therefore I need to show my whole table. I've been thinking of spltting csv-files, inserting into db temporarily etc but the actual issue is showing the table with so much data. Therefore output buffering would be a good solution. Output buffering in the way you're describing makes it a little faster but not fast enough.

Comment: Honestly AJAX is probably the way to go here.

Comment: Yes I've thouht that of that to. The plugin does support pagination (with ajax) so I just have to found a way saving that specific portion of data showing (say 100 rows) with the rest of the total file :-) Thanks. Now I know how to move on! Thanks a lot!